# How to check the intersection of two squares (Not axis aligned)

Tags: algorithm

I would like to check the intersection of two squares which are not axis-aligned. I know how to do it for axis-aligned squares. Can I extend the same idea?

Basically I want to distribute squares by gaussian distribution on the x-y plane in +ve quadrant say, but two squares should not be intersecting so I have to shift the original center of the square. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Show what you have tried already. Stack Overflow is not a "write my code for me" service.

Comment: I don't want code at all.I just want idea behind how to find two randomly oriented square intersect or not . I know there is parallel axis separation algorithm. But as I am working with square I am thinking We may use its symmetry we can find it in constant time.I have already implemented it for axis parallel square.

Comment: Would [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) suit better for this question? At least it doesn't look related to C++ lang.

Comment: Squares, more generally convex polygons are monotone polygons, so their edges can (in any specific orientation) be decomposed into ordinary polygonal chains, which in turn are monotone with respect to a chosen axis. Then squares intersect iff their chains intersect or one is embedded in the other ('point in polygon' problem).

Answer (score 0):

[Separating axis theorem](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MethodOfSeparatingAxes.pdf)  ([link2](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/collision-detection-using-the-separating-axis-theorem--gamedev-169)) is suitable for effective checking of convex polygon intersection. For squares prerequisite (normals and so on) calculation becomes especially simple.

Comment: So basically you iterate through all edges of both polygons and check if there is an edge that has all other polygon's vertices in front of it. Am I reading it right?

Comment: @rostok Yes, you are right. For rectangles it is faster to get projections on two perpendicular axes through rectangle center.

Comment: OK boss I got :) @MBo

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, you can proceed as follows:

- rotate both `Sa` and `Sb` so that `Sa` becomes axis-aligned;
- check overlap of `Sa'` with the bounding box of `Sb'`;
- rotate both `Sa` and `Sb` so that `Sb` becomes axis-aligned;
- check overlap of the bounding box of `Sa"` with `Sb"`.

If there is a configuration with no overlap, then the squares are disjoint.

[image]

In analytical terms, the no-overlap conditions will have a form like

```
C1 + C2 (|cos(t1+t2)| + |sin(t1+t2)|) < 2D Min(|cos(t1)|, (|sin(t1)|)
```

where `C1`, `C2` are the sides, `D` the distance between centers and `t1`, `t2` are the angles between sides and the center line, and similar by exchange of `1`/`2`.

Comment: This is way to exploit the separating axis theorem cited by @Mbo.

Comment: CAUTION: errors in the formula are not excluded, double check.

Answer (score 0):

After almost 4-5 hours of thinking, I got one click. Just sharing if anyone needs this. PseudoCode

Input: Square1 and Square2

```
Bool(Sqaure1,square2)
  for vertex v0 to v3 of sqaure 1
    angle = 0;
    for vertex P0 to P3 of square 2 (In anticlockwise of clockwise way)
        angle = angle + angle(Pj,vi,P((j+1)%4)); 
    if(abs(angle-360) == 0)
        return true;

  return false;
```

IDEA: point of one square  inside or on the line of another square will have angle sum of 360 with all points if two squares intersects.So you can call function twice by swapping arguments and if anyone returns true then answer  is yes.(Call twice or check if angle sum is 0 or 360 exactly)

Comment: That will fail for the seal of Melchizedek in which each vertex of a square lies outside the other square, but squares intersect anyway... http://sealofmelchizedek.com/2011/06/13/what-is-the-seal-of-melchizedek-2/

Comment: @CiaPan Ohhh.. Thanks for pointing out.....:)..Can you suggest a patch in my code which can check this condition tooo

Comment: See my comment below the OP's question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339832/how-to-check-the-intersection-of-two-squares-not-axis-aligned#comment45026157_28339832